# else if pagination issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, if-statement, pagination

I have a page that will show 8 posts at a time.  I grouped them into groups of 4.  When the user wants to read the 2nd pair of 4 posts, they will need to click on the 'load more' button and the 2nd group of 4 post will show.

Now the issue I'm having is going back having the same situation happen when the user clicks on the the other paginated pages.  After clicking 'load more', all the posts in the other paginated pages show 8 posts.

So I wrote this code, however, the else statement is not being read.

This is the code I wrote trying to do exactly what I'm saying:

```
$('#ysports-news').on('click', '.pager-list-262 span.pager', function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    console.log('this is sparta');
  } else {
    console.log('May the force be with you');
    $('.postGroups:odd').addClass('kc-hidden');
    $('.ys-pgrid img').removeClass('kc-hidden');
  }
});
```

The current paginated page has the class .active, and all the paginations are span within .pager-list-262 with the class .pager.

What I'm trying to achieve is, when I click on 'load more' show the last 4 posts, then hide the 'load more' button. When I click on a different page, hide the last 4 posts(odd groups) and show the load more button again.

console.log('this is sparta') works fine, but the else statement is not being read. Is it a problem with my syntax?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

edit: I decided to put the html of the pagination to help anyone that might need it. I didn't include what's in the span, because its just the text for the pagination that we see on the site.

```
<div class="pager-list pager-list-262">
  <span class="pager page-prev" data-page="page"></span>
  <span class="pager page-number active" data-page="1"></span>
  <span class="pager page-number" data-page="2"></span>
  <span class="pager page-prev disabled" data-page="page"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Without html to represent a [mcve] there isn't enough information to work from. Don't need all the internal elements of a post but need an html basic structure as well as some idea how paging works

Comment: @charlietfl was actually thinking the exact same thing, and just included the html concerning the pagination. If you need more, I will gladly post more. And thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Still not clear what *"all the posts in the other paginated pages"* refers to

Comment: @charlietfl I have a total of 16 tests posts right now. In the first paginated page, I show 8 of those posts, and in the next paginated page I show 8 more posts.

Comment: But what does *"next paginated page"* mean exactly?  A newly loaded page in browser or part of same page currently in browser?

Comment: @charlietfl its part of the same page, because its running via ajax. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: All this is still a bit too fragmented to get a grasp on troubleshooting your issue.